# Visual C++ 2005 can't find dxtrans.h despite the fact that it's in the first folder in my include directories

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, directx, directx-9

I have the 2007 directx sdk include directory set as the first entry in the Include Files directory list in Visual C++ 2005, and that directory contains dxtrans.h. Yet when I try to build my project, I get "To compile qedit.h you must install the DirectX 9 SDK, to obtain the dxtrans.h header.", accompanied by hundreds of syntax errors in windows sdk headers (amstream.h, qedit.h, etc). Is there some other magic incantation I need to perform in order to get the compiler to find dxtrans.h? Is the error message a red herring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a red herring.  That message is always displayed:

```
#pragma message("To compile qedit.h you must install the DirectX 9 SDK, to obtain the dxtrans.h header.")
```

Pay attention to the first few *real* compiler error messages, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 2):

open a new file： dxtrans.h
please paste follow content into the file, then move file to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include

```
/* Fixes issue with Windows SDK */
#define __IDxtCompositor_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#define __IDxtAlphaSetter_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#define __IDxtJpeg_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
#define __IDxtKey_INTERFACE_DEFINED__
```